# C++ how to use strcpy for a 2d array in a struct

Tags: c++, strcpy

My compiler gives me an error when I do this:

```
strcpy(skin.conclusion[0], "Mel");
```

My struct looks like this:

```
struct list{
        char conclusion[10][4] = {};
    }skin;
```

What am I doing wrong or is there something else other than strcpy that I'm supposed to use.

Comment: `char conclusion[10][3] = {};`  conclusion is only three characters long.  `strcpy(skin.conclusion[0], "Mel");`  "Mel" is four characters long (remember the string terminator character...)  The compiler can do anything if you invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: Or just C++ `std::string`.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks, but that still doesn't get strcpy to work.

Comment: If I copy less characters that it can hold then it works for me:  https://onlinegdb.com/xX_szfLeG  Make sure you `#include <string.h>`

Comment: The only error I got was when I said it was a C program and then `char conclusion[10][4] = {};` didn't work because empty braces is a C++ thing.  For C you need `char conclusion[10][4] = {0};`   You should really put a `C` or `C++` tag on the question so people know how to help you (but not both!)

Comment: The link I gave above works for C++.  But if you are using C then this works: https://onlinegdb.com/4OkZ3dvDG

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full code that worked for me. Of course, this is C style C++ and not modern C++, there are many reasons to prefer std::string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> 


struct list{
        char conclusion[10][4] = {};
}
skin;
int main()
{
    strcpy(skin.conclusion[0], "Mel");
    std::cout<<skin.conclusion[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To be fair he didn't actually put a C or C++ tag on the question, and since his code didn't compile as C (the empty braces) I assumed he was using a C++ compiler but it is possible he didn't want to be using C++ and wanted to be using C all along.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah good point, but since the title explicitly said C++ I thought I'd throw him/her a heads up that in the year 2021 he prbly shouldn't be doing this if he has access to a C++ compiler :)

Comment: Sorry - my apologies.  I didn't notice that at all.  I have added the appropriate language tag.